# Java Ugly Rounding Error?

Tags: java, charts, rounding, jfreechart

Using `series.add(180, 1);` produces a perfectly valid chart like this (little red dot at the bottom with some PolarItemRenderer Mods!)

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1269795283096077100.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1269795283096077100.png)

but using `series.add(3000/(6000/360), 1);` produces this beast:

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1269795508054503400.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1269795508054503400.png)

I assume it's because somewhere, 6000/360 = 16.6... is getting rounded? How can I stop this happening? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry about the massive screenies!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using integer division. 3000/(6000/360) = 3000 / 16 = 187.
I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but use doubles instead of integers if you don't want the integer division.